# How to generate the html form data in the qr code?

Tags: html, qr-code

I have searched many way in the online to find how to generate the html form data become qr code, but I can't get the suitable result for me. Hope anyone can share the guideline or tutorial for me how to generate the html form data become qr code.

This is my example situation:

I have a form to save the data in the table, after that in the table qr code button when I've clicked, it will show me the qr code picture. If I've scanned the qr code, the content will show me in the phone what I've selected .

[image: sample1]

For example, I want the expected result like below the picture after I've scan the qr code and see the selected result on my phone:

[image: SAMPLE5]

[image: sample2]

Hope someone can guide me or give the logic for me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the answer below. 
if you use JS and Jquery it can be done. 
Link: [Generating a Simple QR-Code with just HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115242/generating-a-simple-qr-code-with-just-html)

Comment: I try to see. Thanks.

Comment: If you onclick() the button "QR Code" and have the function run that way it will work, you have not added your code to the question so difficult to see

Comment: Yes, I am using onclick. How to add your suggest put to my button function?

Comment: Add into QR code button or Save button to generate qr code are better?

Comment: Write your JS function and call it with <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

Comment: See a basic function in action here:
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("field2").value = document.getElementById("field1").value;
}
</script>

Comment: I've tried it still cannot. Can you check my frontend code here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TMirx2hJwIBjMB_sQDHc6ThQYqtffTtP?usp=sharing  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215090/discussion-between-taariq-solomons-and-sunny-ong).